# TypeError when using `df.apply` (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image: Dataframe]

I want to take the log of each value in the dataframe.

So that seemed like no problem at first, and then:
`data.apply(lambda x:math.log(x))` returned a type error (cannot convert series to class 'float').

Okay, fine--so, while type checking is often frowned upon, I gave it a shot (also tried casting x to a float, same problem):

`isinstance((data['A1BG'][0]), np.float64)` returns true, so I tried:

`data.apply(lambda x: math.log(x) if isinstance(x, np.float64) else x)`. That ran without any errors, but it didn't change any values in my dataframe.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the Hybridization column an index? If not, set it as the index first and then call applymap.

Comment: Yes--earlier in the notebook: `data = data.set_index("Hybridization REF")`

Comment: Yes. I'll write an answer explaining what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that `df.apply` returns a `pd.Series` object for the lambda to operate over... It basically operates over a Series at a time, not one float at a time.

So, with

```
data.apply(lambda x: math.log(x) if isinstance(x, np.float64) else x)
```

`isinstance(x, np.float64)` is never true (because `x` is a `pd.Series` type) and so the else is always executed.

To remedy this, you can operate a column at a time, using `df.applymap`:

```
data.applymap(math.log)
```

Using apply, the solution is similar, but you cannot escape the lambda:

```
data.apply(lambda x: np.log(x))
```

Or, alternatively (pd 0.20):

```
data.transform(lambda x: np.log(x))
```

Coincidentally, `df.applymap` is the fastest, followed by `df.apply` and `df.transform`.

Comment: That's a great solution, thank you! Ysearka's solution also works, but this one gives me something that will be more applicable to a wider range of future uses.

Comment: @JulianStanley You can actually shorten your expression. Just pass the callback without a lambda - `applymap(callback)`. Pandas will vectorise it automatically.

Comment: @JulianStanley Just tested on bigger data, and you should stick to apply or transform for large data. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `apply` on a dataframe, the apply function will be cast  upon a `Pandas.Series` not a float (opposing to when you use `apply` on a Series). Then instead of `math.log` you should use `np.log`)

**EDIT:**

With examples it's always better:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b'])
test.a = np.random.random(5)
test.b = np.random.random(5)

    a           b
0   0.430111    0.420516
1   0.367704    0.785093
2   0.034130    0.839822
3   0.310254    0.755089
4   0.098302    0.136995
```

If you try the following, it won't work:

```
test.apply(lambda x: math.log(x))

TypeError: ("cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>", 'occurred at index a')
```

But this will do the job:

```
test.apply(lambda x: np.log(x))

    a           b
0   -0.843711   -0.866273
1   -1.000476   -0.241953
2   -3.377588   -0.174565
3   -1.170364   -0.280919
4   -2.319708   -1.987811
```

Comment: Bam. Quick, simple, and worked like a charm. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 import math
 data.apply(lambda x:math.log(list(x)))
```

Comment: This also works, for a similar reason as ColdSpeed's solution--changing an array to a list. Thanks for the help!